# USB debugging on Android

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

I have an android device which is secured with a screen lock. But now I don't remember the password to unlock my phone.

By default, the **USB mode** is set to **always ask** and also the **USB debugging** is disabled.

I tried unlocking my phone using a third party software on pc but it **requires** the **USB debugging** to be **turned on**.

How can I turn on USB debugging in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible precisely because of the security issues it would present if it was.

The only way to access your phone is by doing a factory reset through the recovery mode, but be aware this wipes all of your data.